# Discord.js Cannot get member by ID on ready function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have not used the latest Discord.js version 13 so I am quite unfamiliar with it.

I am trying to get a member by its ID on the client ready function.

```js
client.guilds.cache.get("x").members.cache.get("x")
```

Members returns as `undefined`. This however works with `members.fetch()`, but I am not able to use this in my code.

But for some reason, this code works

```js
 client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => {
     guild.members.cache.forEach((member) => {
       console.log(member)
     });
   });
```

Please help as I have tried this in the previous **Discord.js v12** and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Have you tried logging client.guilds.cache.get(x) to check if the guild exists?

Comment: Yes @Zloth it does exists. Apparently the members wont get cached for whatever reason. I have now resorted with ``members.fetch("x").then(member => {})``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`client.guilds.cache.get("x").members.cache.get("x")`
might not work due to either the guild or the member being uncached hence, unavialable to your client through cache you attemmpted to use `member.fetch()` as you said in your question although were unable to do so, maybe trying a wrong approach? let's try it right here!

```js
client.once("ready", () => {
const guildId = 123456789012345678 // guild you want to fetch
const memberId = 123456789012345678 // member you want to fetch
client.guilds.fetch(`${guildId}`).then( (g) => { g.members.fetch(`${memberId}`) });
});
```

Easy stuff! feel free to comment if you face any other errors!